# Is it possible to post-install disks in raid?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, lenovo

I have just received my new Ubuntu 22.04 workstation from Lenovo (Thinkstation P620)
It has 2 1TB disks, that I want to use in RAID 1 for `/`, and 4 2TB disks that I want to use in RAID 5 for `/home`.
However the machine arrived with Ubuntu already "almost set up", I had only to chose the username and psw, there was no disk management.
So now I have a full desktop with one of the 1TB disk with 3 partitions: two system ones (UEFI and PQSERVICE) and the main space interelly allocated to UBuntu mounted on /.
The other 5 disks are unmounted and unpartitioned.

Can I go from this situation to my required disk set up? Or do I need to reinstall ubuntu from scratch?
What would I loose in installing from a standard Ubuntu image compared to use the Lenovo oem provided one ? (for completeness I don't need the gui/desktop, this machine will be the computational server for our lab)

Comment: It's theoretically possible but MASSIVELY more complex and risky than just reinstalling.

Comment: in general lines and out of curiosity, how it could be achieved @symcbean?

Comment: Have a look at how synology does "flexi" RAID.

Answer (score 0):

If your Ubuntu uses EXT4 or BTRFS as filesystem, it is possible, particularly easy and almost risk free.

It goes in several steps:

1. you convert your EXT4 filesystem to BTRFS filesystem (if not already BTRFS) https://askubuntu.com/questions/198000/how-can-i-convert-an-ext4-partition-to-btrfs-or-other-file-systems-without-los (as it's the root filesystem, this can only be used offline, so use the Ubuntu installer medium (DVD/USB-stick)) - PS the linked tutorial might not be anymore up to date - **PPS read step 2 first**
2. basically you first install `sudo apt-get install btrfs-tools` and also do a `sudo update-grub`, then you reboot once, if all okay, you shutdown and reboot with Ubuntu installation medium and use `btrfs-convert`, see `man btrfs-convert` for help
3. you create partitions boundaries exactly (byte exact) on the second 1TB disk, to mirror the first 1TB disk
4. you use `dd` to copy the UEFI and PQSERVICE from fist 1TB disk to second 1TB disk, make sure to change the UUIDS of the copied volumes, otherwise they cannot be mounted
5. you use `btrfs device add /dev/sdXY /` where `/dev/sdXY` is your 3th empty partition of your second 1TB disk (this will create a JBOD like BTRFS device on-the-fly)
6. then you use `btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /` this will convert the former JBOD like BTRFS device to a RAID1 like BTRFS device
7. you could also use BTRFS to create a RAID5 but it's not recommend if you don't use a uninterruptible power supply (UPS), but you may use BTRFS to span a RAID1 over 3 disks, which is also very solid
8. if you really want to use RAID5 on the other 3 disks - you should use MDADM-RAID, personally I don't recommend to use RAID5 anymore, as it's rebuilding is slow and has a high risk of destroying the remaining disks due overload